# HTML get image by indirect link

Tags: html, spring, image

I have to load an image to HTML page by indirect link. I make request to web server which dynamically generate an image then put it to image storage and return URL for this image as a response.
It's look like this:

```
<img src="https://my.web.server/get-image-link" alt="image"/>
```

And dummy server-side:

```
@RequestMapping("/get-image-link")
class ImageController() {

    @GetMapping
    fun getImage(): String = "https://image.storage/image.jpg"
  
}
```

Browser just show me the 'alt' but not an image. I tried different content types for response header but nothing helps.

There is any opportunity to make the browser show me the image by this generated link?

P.S. I cannot use JS code because this approach will be used in email content.

Comment: The URL doesn't return an image. We can't tell why it doesn't return an image because you haven't shown us the server-side code responsible for the response. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Added server-side code

Comment: I don't know spring very well, but it looks like you are returning a text document with a URL in it. You need to return an image. (Or a redirect response).